# MIPS — print a value in a variable

Tags: mips, system-calls

Following is the code:

```
.text
.ent    main
.type   main, @function
main:
.frame  $fp,24,$31      # vars= 8, regs= 1/0, args= 0, gp= 8

addiu   $sp,$sp,-24
sw  $fp,20($sp)
move    $fp,$sp
li  $2,1            # 0x1
sw  $2,12($fp)
li  $2,1            # 0x1
sw  $2,8($fp)

    # now print -------------------------------------
    li      $2,1
    li      $a0,10
    syscall

move    $2,$0
move    $sp,$fp
lw  $fp,20($sp)
addiu   $sp,$sp,24
j   $31
nop
```

How did I generate this — by writing a single program:

```
int main(){
  int i = 1;
}
```

And then simply added the syscall statements myself. I am unsure if this is right or wrong.

Comment: Does it work as expected? Otherwise you're going to have to specify the environment you're trying to compile/run this code in, and the errors you're getting.

Comment: I mean, it compiles properly and runs without any errors. What it doesn't do — is print the goddamn thing!

Comment: And what are you running this in? SPIM/MARS? What if you run a program that only prints an integer and does nothing else (i.e. none of that stack frame setup code that you got from the compiler)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I solved it was simply using printf call after all. Syscalls never worked for me; even the way described in the answer.

So to print a value 10, I do the following:-

```
    # printf initialized

    lui     $2,%hi($LC0)             # loading .ascii from $LCO
    addiu   $2,$2,%lo($LC0)
    move    $4,$2                # first argument to printf
    li      $5,10
    lw      $2,%call16(printf)($28)      # printf call to print contents of $5
    nop
    move    $25,$2
    jalr    $25
    nop
    lw      $28,16($fp)              # __printf__ end
```

Comment: This looks like an answer for Linux MIPS.  The other answer is for MARS/SPIM.  The question doesn't have enough tags to know, or any info for future readers to know which answer to use.

Answer (score 1):

The code you added:

```
   # now print -------------------------------------
    li      $2,1
    li      $a0,10
    syscall
```

does print the integer 10 in the standard output.
If you wish to print variable `i` you have to load its value first into register `$a0`.
Assuming it is not already stored in a register (which by the way is your case), and that it is stored in the stack (at location 8 relative to `$fp`) you'd have to:

```
  lw $a0, 8($fp)   # Load contents of variable i onto register $a0
  li $v0, 1        # service 1 (print integer)
  syscall          # issue service
```